# Support order, when losing a battle

Tags: game-of-thrones

If a unit with a support order, supports the losing side in a battle, is it routed or can It support again in another battle?

Answer (score 8):

It can support again another battle. Supporting units simply provide their strength in combat without participating in any other way. Routing only happens to retreating armies. See manual page 21 ("Retreats and Routing").